# Append a Json file to an existing Jsonb field in a Postgres table and also update the json file if required

Tags: json, postgresql

There is a table customer and it has a jsonb datatype field named report to hold json files.

The existing Json file in the report jsonb field is as follows

```
{
    "report": {
        "operations-utilization-rightsizing": {
            "default_settings": [{
                "type": "%",
                "radio": "false",
                "range": {
                    "max": 100,
                    "min": 0
                }
            }]
        }
    }
}
```

Now I need to append or merge the below json file to this report field in customer table.

```
 {
    "operations-battery-critical-events": {
        "default_settings": [{
            "type": "%",
            "radio": "false",
            "range": {
                "max": 100,
                "min": 0
            }
        }]
    }
}
```

I tried the following update statement

```
UPDATE customer 
SET report = report || '{
    "operations-battery-critical-events": {
        "default_settings": [{
            "type": "%",
            "radio": "false",
            "range": {
                "max": 100,
                "min": 0
            }
        }]
    }
}' :: jsonb
WHERE report IS NOT NULL;
```

The output for the above SQL is,

```
{
    "report": {
        "operations-utilization-rightsizing": {
            "default_settings": [{
                "type": "%",
                "radio": "false",
                "range": {
                    "max": 100,
                    "min": 0
              }
        }]
    }
},
    "operations-battery-critical-events": {
        "default_settings": [{
                "type": "%",
                "radio": "false",
                "range": {
                    "max": 100,
                    "min": 0
                }
          }]
    }
}
```

And the desired output should be as below,

```
{
    "report": {
        "operations-utilization-rightsizing": {
            "default_settings": [{
                "type": "%",
                "radio": "false",
                "range": {
                    "max": 100,
                    "min": 0
                }
            }]
        },
        "operations-battery-critical-events": {
            "default_settings": [{
                "type": "%",
                "radio": "false",
                "range": {
                    "max": 100,
                    "min": 0
                }
             }]
         }
     }
}
```

I'm new to json, please let me for any further details.

Comment: Please show an example of an existing JSON in your table.  Does `report` contain an array of JSON objects?  Or are you wanting to add this new object under a key in an existing object?  What do you mean by editing the `radionenabled` key?

Comment: @Mike Organek Please find the updated question and let me know your thoughts

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work, but you have to adjust it to whether the top key is `report` (as in your question) or `report_settings` (as in your desired output example).

```
UPDATE customer 
SET report = jsonb_set(report, '{report,operations-battery-critical-events}',
    '{
        "default_settings": [{
            "type": "%",
            "radio": "false",
            "range": {
                "max": 100,
                "min": 0
            }
        }]
    }'::jsonb)
WHERE report IS NOT NULL;
```

Comment: Thanks a lot and it really worked for my requirement, I just added a ) before Where clause.

Comment: @user10531062 Glad it works for you!  Sorry about the error!